# Do lords acquired through confederation have diminished loyalty?

Tags: warhammer-ii-total-war

I'm currently running through a Skaven (Clan Rictus) game in the Battle for the Vortex campaign. I have 5 different lords running about with one of them having been acquired through confederation (named Obsicide for future reference). Every single lord is doing great with loyalty except for Obsicide, who has been losing at least one loyalty almost every single turn.

I've been able to keep them abated by having them constantly capturing settlements and giving them shiny new toys but all of that is only extremely temporary before they go back to critical loyalty for unknown reasons.

Some quick notes:

- My faction leader is level 40
- Thought it might be a distance from capital thing but another lord that is tagging along with Obsicide is not displaying the same symptoms
- They have a fairly strong army with them, definitely not the weakest I have
- I'd prefer not to get rid of them unless there is no other choice, they are quite strong at level 35

The only thing I can think of as to the cause is that they just don't like having to switch sides from the faction I confederated. Is that the reason? Can I sate this ticking time bomb without just replacing them?

Comment: My question is, what type of lord is giving you trouble (wizard or warrior) and what faction are you playing. As queek has a loyalty debuff towards the wizard type.

Comment: @KevinTheGreat The lord is a wizard but I'm playing as Clan Rictus, not Clan Mors, nor do I have Queek as a lord through confederation